# @angular/google-maps how to get the lat and lng of the marker after it is dragged?

Tags: angular, google-maps-api-3

i'm implementing @angular/google-maps official component on Angular.
My issue is with getting the lat and lng values of the newly added marker:

my implementation is exactly as this one https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/google-maps-as-an-angular-component. my issue is that I can't seem to get this value updated.

my HTML:

```
  <google-map *ngIf="pickAddressMode"
            height="500px"
            width="100%"
            [zoom]="zoom"
            [center]="center"
            [options]="options"
            (click)="checkValue()"
            >
              <map-marker
                #markerElem
                *ngFor="let marker of markers"
                [position]="marker.position"
                [label]="marker.label"
                [title]="marker.title"
                [options]="marker.options"
                >
            </map-marker>
          </google-map>
```

my JS:

```
addMarker(data) {
  this.markers = [];
  const coords = data;
  this.center = coords;


  this.markers.push({
    position: {
      ...coords
    },
    options: {
      draggable: true,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    },
  });

  const marker = this.markers[0];

}
```

if I log:

```
checkValue() {
    console.log(this.markers[0].position.lng);
    console.log(this.markers[0].position.lat);
}
```

it's always the same.

I've tried to get the values like this:

```
var lat = this.markers[0].getPosition().lat();
var lng = this.markers[0].getPosition().lng();
```

but it throws error.

```
ReportPage.html:122 ERROR TypeError: this.markers[0].getPosition is not a function
```

how can I get this value updated?

my "dirty" workaround is the following, get the center of the map. a value which I can see it is updating.

```
  return JSON.stringify(this.map.getCenter());
```

I can add a marker in the center of the map and make the user "move" the map to the right position... but the drag experience is way superior.

I have tried to this approach that makes the marker's "methods" work, but then the marker is not loading correctly (no animation, no draggable, even that the options are ok. I think that there is something i must be missing.

When I initialize like this with  new google.maps.Marker(...);

```
addMarker(data) {
      this.markers = [];
      const coords = data;
      this.center = coords;
      this.markers.push(
        new google.maps.Marker(
        {
        map: this.map,
        title: 'Acuario de Gijón',
        label: 'yala',
        options:{
          clickable: true,
          draggable: true,
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        },
        position: {
          ...coords
        },
      }
      )
      );
    }
```

thanks guys!

Comment: All the events seem to be documented in that page you linked in your question...

Comment: yes but somehow the binding on the element is not working. :/

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you push the wrong [Marker instance](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#add).

Here is my solution:

```js
let newMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      ...coords
    },
    options: {
      draggable: true,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    },
});
this.markers.push(newMarker);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the coordinates by listening to "mapDragend" events.
Html:

```
  <google-map *ngIf="pickAddressMode"
        height="500px"
        width="100%"
        [zoom]="zoom"
        [center]="center"
        [options]="options"
        (click)="checkValue()"
        >
          <map-marker
            *ngFor="let marker of markers"
            [position]="marker.position"
            [label]="marker.label"
            [title]="marker.title"
            [options]="marker.options"
            (mapDragend)="onDragend(marker, $event)"
            >
      </map-marker>
   </google-map>
```

JS:

```
public onDragend(m, event){
  this.markers[this.determineIndex(m)].position = event.latLng;
}
```